# Затемнение экрана при обзоре помещения. Виртуальный тур

Tags: unity3d, 3d, virtualtour

Всем привет!
Есть дом (обычная модель на сцене). Если кликнуть по любой квартире, результат должен быть как на скрине. http://iscr.ru/image/vHB9A

Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну либо другую камеру, которая видит определенный слой, либо на основной камере поменять. И обьект перевести на этот слой. На камере выставить background color на черныйю

Comment: Понял, спасибо)